# A simplex is the intersection of closed half spaces

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I have the following exercise in a [course of convex geometry](http://www.math.kit.edu/iag4/lehre/konvgeo2009w/media/cg.pdf) by Hug and Weil :

Let $P$ be a simplex with $n+1$ vertices $x_0,\dots, x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $P$ is the convex hull of $n+1$ affine independent points $x_0,\dots, x_n$. Let $E_i$ be the affine hull of $\{x_0\dots,x_n\}\setminus\{x_i\}$ and $H_i$ the closed half space bounded by $E_i$ containing $x_i$. Show that $$P=\bigcap_{i=0}^n H_i.$$

For the first part it is easy to see that $P$ is included in each $H_i$ and hence is included in their intersection. For the other inclusion, I would take $x\in \bigcap_{i=0}^n H_i$ and write $x=\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_ix_i$ with $\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i=1$. Since $x\in H_i$, I am sure that $\alpha_i$ must be nonnegative, however I do not know how to prove the latter.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ x\not \in P$. Write $x= \sum_k \lambda_k x_k$ where $\lambda_k$ are the barycentric coordinates of $x$ with respect to $x_0,...,x_n$. Note that since the $x_k$ are affinely independent, the
coordinates are unique.

Since $ x \not \in P$, we have $\lambda_{k'} < 0$ for at least one $k'$. Then $x \not \in H_{k'}$.

Hence $P^c \subset (\cap_k H_k)^c$.

**Addendum**:

You can define $H_i$ as either $\{ (1-\lambda)\sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k x_k + \lambda x_i| \sum_k \lambda_{k \neq i} =1, \lambda \ge 0 \}$ or equivalently
$\{ \lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) e | \lambda \ge 0, e \in E_i \}$.

Comment: Can you explain carefully how $\lambda_{k'}<0$ implies that $x\notin H_{k'}$?

Comment: What I think is that we can represent, say, $E_0$ as $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ where $f$ is a linear form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Then suppose that $f(x_0)>\alpha$, we get $H_0=\{x:f(x)\geq \alpha\}$. This representation of $H_0$ will help us to show that $\alpha_0\geq 0$. However I do not really like this proof because it needs a precise definition of $H_i$. I expect to have a more geometric proof...

Comment: @mapping: I added a definition of $H_i$. Giving a geometric proof requires that you define the term 'containing'.

Comment: I guess you get what you pay for.